# What do the "Evil Spirits" have to do with a house becoming leprous?

Tags: short-stories, yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer

In Isaac Bashevis Singer's short story "Stories From Behind the Stove", one character associates the "Evil Ones" with being capable of anything, giving a leprous house as an example:

> Two weeks passed. The simple people had other things to worry about. We young men in the study house did discuss the matter, but for all of our pondering we came to the same conclusion : it was done by mocking demons. Doesn't the Bible tell us that even a house can become leprous? The Evil Ones are capable of anything.

Why is a leprous house associated with "Evil Ones"? As far as I'm aware, leprosy - including on a house - is more associated with [lashon hara](https://outorah.org/p/257/), slanderous speech, and comes from God. Why is this given as an example of the power of the Evil Ones?